# NSS error when starting google-chrome in cent os 7

Tags: google-chrome, centos7, nss

This is my first question.

I have been very confused by this for more than a month.

Google Chrome always crashes with an NSS error.

The error message message is: 
*"Error initializing NSS without a persistent database".*

I have re-installed Chrome, but the same error occurs and I do not know how to solve this.

P.S. Chromium also does not work, but FireFox does work.

> $ google-chrome
>   [24107:24107:0528/193723:ERROR:url_pattern_set.cc(240)] Invalid url
>   pattern: chrome://print/* [7:7:0528/193723:ERROR:nss_util.cc(207)]
>   Error initializing NSS without a persistent database: NSS error code:
>   -8023 [7:7:0528/193723:FATAL:nss_util.cc(209)] nss_error=-8023, os_error=0

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in centos 7. It looks like there is some conflict between nss libraries . I uninstalled firefox, installed chrome, installed firefox again and then started chrome . This issue got fixed.